# Certain strings with parenthesis cause Ajax POST operation to fail with 403 error (forbidden)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, post

When attempting to add an entry to a database via a form submission using Ajax, certain strings containing parenthesis will cause the POST operation to fail, but not in a consistent way.

The relevant POST operation looks like this:

```
$.ajax(
{
  type: "POST",
  url: "SubmitAnswer.php",
  data: datastring,
  dataType: "json",
  cache: false,
  success: function(data)
  {
    ...
  }
}
```

The `datastring` contains a bunch of stuff including a string containing a mathematical expression. If that string contains parenthesis, in certain very specific cases, it will cause the POST operation to fail with a 403 error when the Submit button is clicked.

Here are some examples of mathematical expression strings that cause a problem:

```
(A-B)*C
(A*B)*(C*D)
```

Here are some examples of mathematical expression strings that do NOT cause a problem:

```
(A+B)*C
A*(B-C)
(A*B)+(C*D)
```

It's almost as though certain permutations trip some kind of "protection" flag preventing them from being posted to the database? Or some kind of bizarre parsing error?

Comment: What is an example `datastring`? Please show the **exact** asignment operation. It should start with `var datastring = ...`

Comment: Also, what is the full response from your server? You can see it in your browser's *Network* console

Comment: var datastring = 'edition_id='+edition_id+'&nickname='+nickname+'&answer='+answer+'&email_address='+email_address;

Comment: Right, so absolutely no encoding of the keys or values in that string. See my answer below

Comment: I can provide this additional information associated with the error: jquery-1.10.0.js:8715 and the jquery line triggering the error is: xhr.send( ( s.hasContent && s.data ) || null );

Answer (score 2):

Ok, so following Phil's advice, I checked the server logs to get more information on the 403 error those very specific strings were causing and the problem has to do with those strings being "seen" as SQL injection attacks by a security mechanism on the server. I'll post a new question on how that can be addressed (apparently there is an exception list that you can configure) as that is a very different question than the original.

Answer (score 1):

Doesn't look like you are correctly encoding the keys and / or values in `datastring` for use in an `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` request payload.

My advice, let jQuery do the encoding by passing an object, eg

```
$.ajax({
  method: 'POST',
  url: 'SubmitAnswer.php',
  dataType: 'json',
  data: {
    edition_id: edition_id,
    nickname: nickname,
    answer: answer,
    email_address: email_address
  }
})
```

Comment: I tried the suggestion above (except I kept the cache: false parameter, but the same specific answer strings still cause the POST to fail.

Comment: Some of the variables that are passed in data {} MAY not be strings since they were assigned a value based off val() so I'm not sure if that includes quotation marks, that might cause an issue? For example, earlier in the code I get the values from the fields as follows: var answer = $('#answer').val(); var nickname = $('#nickname').val(); var email_address = $('#emailAddress').val(); But the strange thing is that the failed POST/Submit issue only crops up for very specific answer strings which is very strange.

Comment: @KenBoone what **exactly** is the response text for the failed requests. Check your browsers *Network* console. You can also check the server error log, it may hold more clues. Also, `POST` requests are never cached anyway and all values returned by `.val()` are strings.

Comment: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 (Forbidden). It references the php file listed in the URL parameter of the ajax routine.

Comment: @KenBoone I suggest then you check your server's error log. Do you have any URL rewriting enabled on the server-side?

Comment: Yes, OK, I see the log entry and it is along the lines of what I was suggesting, a security mechanism is preventing the POST because it sees that string as a potential security breach: ModSecurity: file "/etc/httpd/modsecurity.d/11_asl_adv_rules.conf"] [line "81"] [id "341245"] [rev "37"] [msg "Atomicorp.com WAF Rules: SQL injection attack (detectSQLi)"] [data "1)o1,ARGS:answer"] [severity "CRITICAL"] [tag "SQLi"] Access denied with code 403 (phase 2). detected SQLi using libinjection with fingerprint '1)o1'